# How to execute multi cmd one by one in the window of first cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have 3 commands to execute one by one, very command should be waitting until previous command executed successful. 2nd and 3rd command should be executed in command window of **vcvarsall.bat**, can't in multi-windows.

1,

```
cmd /k D:\"Program Filesx86"\"Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"\VC\vcvarsall.bat x64
```

2,

```
cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

3,

```
nmake
```

how can I merge 3 cmds in one bat file?

I want to do like this:

```
cmd /k "D:\Program Filesx86\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64 && "cmake -G'NMake Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../custom_msg/"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `&&` means run command if previous command successful. `&` is the command joiner. But you've only have two commands. 2 and 3 aren't separated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer next approach in a `.bat` script:

```
rem pushd "full path to working directory (project home)"
Call "D:\Program Filesx86\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
nmake
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the simplest thing is to run your batch file with a `call`.  This will execute `vcvarsall.bat` in the current window, then finish, and then run the next two commands sequentially after that.

```
call "D:\Program Filesx86\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
nmake
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always use:

```
start /wait cmd /k D:\"Program Filesx86"\"Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"\VC\vcvarsall.bat x64
start /wait cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
start /wait nmake
```